# Make web-page accessible only after the user completes an action

Tags: html, upload

I am working on a project where users purchase a page of the site and are able to upload stuff to that page. At the moment, when the user pays using PayPal, they are taken straight to the upload page, which is good, however, this page is also accessible by anyone - even if they did not purchase the rights to it. Is there a way to 'protect' the upload page, to only allow proper purchasers to use it themselves? Some sort of system that would detect the PayPal payment and then redirect them to a temporary upload URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is to use Paypal's [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) (Instant Payment Notification) service. The IPN service triggers a notification when an event occurs that pertains to a transaction.

Paypal also has [webhooks](https://devblog.paypal.com/webhook-for-rest-apis-launched/) too.